How can I add in pyproject.toml an optional dependency driven at built by a local environment variable?
With setup.py I can do something like this :
if not os.environ.get("DO_NOT_INSTALL_THIS_PACKAGE"):
    install_requires.append("this_package")

How can I do the same thing with pyproject.toml ? Can I use a local environment variable at built ?
I need to do that in a case where "this_package" provides a bunch of C-libraries needed by my python package. In some cases, the libraries are available on my system but for some reasons there is no wheel provided by "this_package" on PyPi for the python version I use, so in these cases I would like to drive "this_package" dependency by the content of a local environment variable (i.e. if the librairies are available on my system, I do not need this dependency, dependency which is anyway unavailable for the python version I use).

That's not how you would go about it, the proper way would be utilizing optional dependencies.
Basically:
[project]
dependencies = [
  "mandatory_dep1",
  "mandatory_dep2",
  "mandatory_dep3",
  "mandatory_dep4",    
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
incl = [
  "optional_dep1",
]

Then basically you reverse your logic i.e. you add parameter when you want to install dependency, remove when you don't, so:
pip install pckg[incl] 

acts like if your env var would not be set vs
pip install pckg 

if your env var would be set
